# How to reference the property of a protocol that is an associatedType?

Tags: swift, generics, network-programming

I have a `NetworkProvider` class that handles my network requests and is instantiated with an `associatedtype` of a `TargetType` protocol that defines what's needed for an endpoint.

Right now I utilize NetworkProvider as follows:

```swift
let provider = NetworkProvider<IMDBAPI>()
provider.request<[Movie]>(IMDBAPI.getTop250Movies){
    //When successful returns HTTPResponse.success([Movie])
}
```

Right now the `request<T: Decodable>` must reference a Decodable model. However I'd like to be able to have this inferred from the `IMDBAPI.getTop250Movies` as this will always return an array of `Movie` objects so it seems counterproductive to require a developer to have advance knowledge of what the return type of an endpoint is prior to utilising it.

Is it possible to infer the model returned by an an Endpoint/TargetType through the associatedtype protocol passed to it?

---

***Code***

**TargetType**

```
public protocol TargetType {

    var baseURL: URL { get }

    var path: String { get }

    var method: HTTPMethod { get }

    var headers: [String: String]? { get }

    var task: HTTPRequestTask { get }

    //var returnType: Decodable? { get } //This is what I'd like to use.
}
```

**NetworkProvider**

```
public protocol NetworkProviderType {
    associatedtype Target: TargetType
}

public class NetworkProvider<Target: TargetType>: KindredProviderType {

    public func request<T: Decodable>(_ target: Target, handler: @escaping (HTTPResponse<T>) -> ()) {

        let endpoint = NetworkProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)

        guard let urlRequest = try? endpoint.urlRequest() else {
            return handler(HTTPResponse.error(HTTPError.failedToCreate(url: endpoint.url)))
        }

        session.runDataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            let result = HTTPResponse<T>.createFrom(url: urlRequest.url!, error: error, data: data, response: response)

            if case let HTTPResponse.error(error) = result {
                loggingPrint(error)
            }
            handler(result)
        })
    }
}
```

**Example TargetType Implementation**

```
enum SplunkService {
    case recordLogin(report: SplunkJourneyReporting)
    case recordGameLaunch(report: SplunkJourneyReporting)
    case recordError(report: SplunkEventReport)
}

extension SplunkService: TargetType {
    var task: HTTPRequestTask {
        switch self {
        case .recordError(let report):
            return HTTPRequestTask.requestBodyParameters(report.toDictionary())
        case .recordGameLaunch(let report), .recordLogin(let report):
            return HTTPRequestTask.requestBodyParameters(report.toDictionary())
        }
    }

    var baseURL: URL { return URL(string: "https://api.unibet.com")! }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .recordLogin(_):
            return "/eum-collector/journeys/login/reports"
        case .recordGameLaunch(_):
            return "/eum-collector/journeys/game_launch/reports"
        case .recordError(_):
            return "/eum-collector/events"
        }
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .post
    }

    var headers: [String: String]? {
        return [HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue: "application/json"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.  Please review the following comment inline with the code I attached...

```
// the compiler understand exactly what type `T` is because we `init` the class using `T` and that is also the same type used to conform to `TargetType`, in other words if I do `NetworkProvider(returnType: decodableThing)`, the compiler knows that `T` = (the class of `decodableThing`)
```

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

public protocol TargetType {

    associatedtype ReturnTypeUsed: Decodable

    var returnType: ReturnTypeUsed? { get } //This is what I'd like to use.
}

public class NetworkProvider<T> {

    // The compiler understand exactly what type `T` is because we `init` the class using `T` and that is also the same type used to conform to `TargetType`
    // in other words if I do `NetworkProvider(returnType: decodableThing)`, the compiler knows that `T` = (the class of `decodableThing`)
    public typealias ReturnTypeUsed = T

    public var returnType: T?

    init(returnType: T) {
        self.returnType = returnType
    }

}

class Movie: Decodable {

}

let someMovie = Movie()

class IMDBAPI: TargetType {

    var returnType: Movie?

}

let networkProvider = NetworkProvider(returnType: someMovie)

print(networkProvider.returnType) // returns `Optional(__lldb_expr_5.Movie)
```

Comment: Would this mean that every endpoint of a target enum must have the same returnType? I would like to use returnType in the same way I use the other properties so I can return different return types for different endpoints.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed I didn't include an implementation of TargetType, I'll add this now. Perhaps my problem is I'm using an enum. I think your method would work if I defined each endPoint separately as a Struct. Although with structs I'd likely have to repeat a lot of code (i.e in my example all three of the endpoints are very similar.)

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna In my code, once you instantiate `NetworkProvider<T>`, `T` is now fixed, which may not be what you want.  Remember, we use `PATs` (Protocols with Associated Types) when type relationships matter, not when they don't.  It allows us to create customizable behavior based on the relationship of types.  If all you want is type erasure, then `PATs` aren't needed.